# Last resort for wireframing and mockups on ubuntu

Tags: 16.04

After 3 days of research looking for a application (I could install locally) for creating modern mockups and wireframes for my web clients I have yet to find any for Ubuntu.

I've managed to find quite a few that work online(cloud) and look pretty modern and work well on all platforms(linux included); however, sometimes I go to my local library, due to the quietness, to work and sometimes there internet is slow.

So my goal was to find a modern wireframe/mockup program that runs locally (not online) on ubuntu. On this laptop I'am currently dual booting windows 10 and ubuntu 16.04; and I don't want to switch OS everytime i need to create/edit a wireframe or mockup.

Comment: I don't know a lot about webapp wireframes, but wine will work with a lot of programs. Try checking some of the ones you're familiar with in http://appdb.winehq.org

Comment: @brndn2k I'am aware of wine, winetricks, and PlayOnLinux; but...these programs tend to be buggy and crash a lot. Thanks for the feedback though.

Comment: What about a VM with Windows inside? There are plenty of guides for that.

Comment: @brndn2k true but I've never been a big fan of virtual machines but I might try it in future. I just prefer to partition my hard drive and install the OS. thanks though

Comment: I've used Pencil for several of my projects, and it does the job quite well https://pencil.evolus.vn/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I am using Draw.io offline version withe the DEB package for linux. Its is free and runs pretty good on Ubuntu.

https://about.draw.io/integrations/#integrations_offline

Comment: Thanks. Its been a while sonce a wrote that post cause i know use mac osx for web development, but i will check it out. Thinking of messing with linix again anyways. 

Comment: Good luck with that :D

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found some wireframing and mockup programs I could install locally on ubuntu.

ForeUI (http://www.foreui.com/)
wireframesketcher (http://wireframesketcher.com/)

However, I'am looking for something a bit more when it comes to mockups. I will download the wireframesketcher program, but... I think I'll just stick to online web mockup tools since I don't wanna keep switching back and fourth to OS.